# Building spark without any hadoop dependencies

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I found some references to `-Phadoop-provided` flag for building spark without hadoop libraries but cannot find a good example of how to use it. how can I build spark from source and make sure it does not add any of it's own hadoop dependencies. it looks like when I built the latest spark it included a bunch of `2.8.x` hadoop stuff which conflicts with my cluster hadoop version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark has download options for "pre-built with user-provided Hadoop", which are consequently named with `spark-VERSION-bin-without-hadoop.tgz`

If you would really like to build it, then run this from the project root

```
./build/mvn -Phadoop-provided -DskipTests clean package
```